# GAS: This application was created by another user, not by Google

Tags: google-apps-script

I have made a script that is running as a 'Apps Script Gadget' in Google Sites. The script has access to my email and calender etc. because I need notifications if someone has used my script.

When I go to the site as "noname" user I get the message "This application was created by another user, not by Google. This application has access to the following personal information: email address." How do I get rid of this, the user is not interested if the script sends me a email or not.

Thank you for any advises.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If your script is not reliant on any of the users' information, I would suggest when deploying the web app to "Execute the app as" me.  In the Publish > Deploy As Web App... pop-up, there's a dropdown for this.

Comment: This is what I already tried. 1. Publish > Deploy As Web App 2. Dropdown "Execute the app as" Me 3. Dropdown "Execute rights" Anyone, also anonymous. Actually this was the only combination to make the  'Apps Script Gadget' visible to "noname" users. But the problem is the message I mentioned in my question.

Comment: The code itself runs fine, everything works also for "noname" user. The only problem is the message  "This application was created by another user, not by Google. This application has access to the following personal information: email address." The UI was created with GUI-builder.

Comment: Sorry, in the code was commented! the line   //var emailAddress = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(); That caused the problem! Thanks for trying to help me! :-)

Comment: But the part "This application was created by another user, not by Google." still remains. How to get rid of it?

Comment: Yep, even commented lines will give give users messages like that.  I figured it was something in the code.  Don't know how they are going to get the users email address anyways though if they are not logged into Google.  There are a bunch of issues open with the "This application was created by another user" issue on Google's issue log, I'll take a look around and see if they ever did anything about it.

Comment: This getActiveUser().getEmail() works in closed Intranet sites because you have to be logged in to use the Intranet. In open Internet solutions the email address can be hard coded. This all makes sense but that you get messages of commented code lines does not make any sense to me.

Comment: Looks like someone put in another issue in the apps issues list today.  [Apps Issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2069)

Comment: It seems Google is not interessed in this case, Close this.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me; I commented out all references to the Session object but I still got the popup message.

When I removed the commented code entirely and re-published, everything worked fine.  The message about access to the email info was gone.

I guess the google code holds onto an internal library reference even if there is commented code.  Does not make much sense to me.  But hope this helps.