# Google App Script Warning

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have created an app script using user account 1 and used the script on a Google site. When I view the site using user account 2 , I receive a warning message which can be dismissed.
 I have made a copy of the same script on the same site, however there is no option to dismiss this script. I would like to know what would cause this problem as the new script is an exact copy of the old script.

Copy Script https://i.stack.imgur.com/R151l.jpg

Original Script https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIyhm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the warning DOES NOT APPEAR then it doesn't show up if you're logged in as the owner of this script (app). 
If you made the copy from account2 and are viewing it from the same then you won't see it.

Comment: Please check the links to the screenshots I have pasted in the above question. I have created the script and the copy from the same account. However, on the site, I get different types of warnings as shown in the images when I login using another account. One is dismissable while other isn't.

Comment: I tried to replicate this. When I explicitly use the ...setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
I get the dismiss-able warning. And without that I get the permanent.
You can try to do the same and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes it worked. Now I am able to get a dismiss-able warning. Now, is it possible to disable the warning permanently or any method by which the warning doesn't appear at all? Does it appear if I have a google apps for work account? @karan

Comment: you might not be able to disable it permanently if you're trying to access user's data. Similar question here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323395/gas-this-application-was-created-by-another-user-not-by-google

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Chrome on iPhone 4 and script 1 does not work when I use the following lines to call my html page, however the same script works with Chrome installed on Android and PC.

Script1:

```
 output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
```

However, when I use the following code, it works.
Script 2:

```
  output.setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
```

Now, the problem with script 1 is that I get a warning which is dismissable (This application is created by another user.), with script 2 I cannot dismiss the warning. That is why I want to use script 1 universally.

Will someone help me know how can I make script 1 work on Chrome for iOS?